# Downloading multiple files in parallel with changed names

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I'm writing bash script and don’t know how to solve my problem.

I want to to download multiple files at the same time , but ... I want to save the files under modified names.

I have a variable with urls.

```
example.com/aaa.txt
example.com/ooo/bbbbbb.txt 
example.info/c.txt
```

The order of the URL is important.

After downloading I want:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

I tested parallel and wget. But I do not know how to change the file names.

PS: Limit of 5 simultaneous downloads.

Answer (score 0):

what i really need is to see a sample of your variable of URLs. but nonetheless, here's the basis of what i'm thinking:

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash

 end=$(wc -l URLs.txt | sed 's/\ .*//g')
 x=1

 while read URL; do

         until [ $x -eq $end ]; do

                wget $URL --output-document=$x.txt
                x=$(($x+1))

         done

 done < URLs.txt
```

i'll edit it if you have more infomation, but at the moment i've set it up so that it reads URLs.txt which has to be one URL per line and in the same directory

Comment: Your script is very similar to my code. Unfortunately this isn’t what I'm looking for. 

In your example, the files aren’t downloaded in parallel. In the loop runs only one wget. It works but it is slow. 

My URL receives from analysis file directory.djvu (djvudump ./directory.djvu)

Comment: perhaps make five separate URL.txt files and try: 

`bash script1.sh & bash script2.sh & bash script3.sh & bash script4.sh & bash5.sh &`

Comment: I also thought about it. I hope I can find a better solution.

Comment: `length=$(wc -l URLs.txt | cut -f1 -d ' ') && split -d -l $(($length/5)) URLs.txt URLs.txt` would make the splitting fast

Comment: seems like alot of results here:
https://startpage.com/do/search?lui=english&language=english&cat=web&query=run+wget+multiple+times+simultaneously&nj=0

Comment: When I use something like that: parallel -j 6 wget -nv -i $urls Downloading files works great. But how to change the files name?

Comment: could you rename them separately after downloading ? or they all have the same names, i'm guessing ? i doubt you can tie different outputs to the `wget` command using `parallel`, given that `wget --output-document` would rewrite them all over each other. but maybe there's a way, but i haven't used `parallel` before

Comment: > could you rename them separately after downloading ? 
Now I did it.